# wp_options siteurl and home hardcoded?

Tags: site-url, options, home-url

We received a WordPress site from the marketing team of our company and we successfully managed to get it up and running on a staging server but, we have now moved it to production and realized that we had to update the `wp_options` table, specifically the `siteurl` and `home` values, to reflect the new IP address. But what about when we actually assign an FQHN via DNS, should we update this two records once again? Isn't it possible for WordPress to automatically interpret this kind of changes, or perhaps an alternate solution?

Comment: I'm not familiar with FQHN, but if it just means you're pointing your DNS record to your server, as long as you have the user-readable URL (i.e. mysite.com, not an IP address) in the siteurl and home values, you're good to go.

Comment: @WebElaine yes, that's it ([FQHN](http://dret.net/glossary/fqhn)), but then what's the goal of the function `wp_guess_url()`? Can't one just use those values for such options?

Comment: Best I can tell, wp_guess_url(I) is do determine the site URL before WP is installed, so it's before siteurl and home values have been set.

Comment: `siteurl` and `home` are values stored in `wp_options` as you already know. Almost everyone who want to know the value of `siteurl` will use [`get_site_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/), a function that reads `siteurl` from database. That is why a "search and replace" in database is needed when [moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) **if URLs change**. For me, this was also surprise when I met WordPress.